# How to make PostgreSQL start at boot time in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, upstart

Every time I boot my computer, I need to start Posgtres manually via

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4 start
```

It was an easy task to make it start automatically with Init in place: just add a symlink to the script to the appropriate /etc/rcN.d/ directory.

Now, with Upstart... My runlevel is 2 (if that is still applicable) and the symlink is definitely there:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  24 2009-11-15 12:36 S19postgresql-8.4 -> ../init.d/postgresql-8.4
```

However, it still does not start and I have no idea why. I don't even know where to look for the appropriate logs, as /var/log/messages does not seem to be the right place anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [thread at the Ubuntu forms](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1305226&page=2) (post [#15](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8544915&postcount=15)) indicates that this is a problem for Upstart 0.6.3-11, and have been successful with Upstart 0.6.3-10. Excerpt:

> On the 20th I innocently upgraded the packages suggested by the Update Manager. Next day upon re-boot I found that Apache and Postgresql no longer started.
>
> Solution: downgrade Upstart 0.6.3-11 to 0.6.3-10. Apache and Postgresql work normally now.
>
> How? Using the Synaptic Package Manager search for upstart. Select it and then under Package click on Force Version. You get to choose between 0.6.3-11 and 0.6.3-10. Choose 10 and click on apply.

Comment: Cool, hopefully they can get that fixed.